# ipyparallel displaying "registration: purging stalled registration"

Tags: ipython, zeromq, pyzmq, ipython-parallel

I am trying to use the ipyparallel library to run an ipcontroller and ipengine on different machines.

My setup is as follows:

**Remote machine**:
Windows Server 2012 R2 x64, running an ipcontroller, listening on port 5900 and ip=0.0.0.0.

**Local machine**:
Windows 10 x64, running an ipengine, listening on the remote machine's ip and port 5900.

**Controller start command**:
ipcontroller --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=5900 --reuse --log-to-file=True

**Engine start command**:
ipengine --file=/c/Users/User/ipcontroller-engine.json --timeout=10 --log-to-file=True

I've changed the interface field in ipcontroller-engine.json from "tcp://127.0.0.1" to "tcp://" for ipengine.

On startup, here is a snapshot of the ipcontroller log:

`2016-10-10 01:14:00.651 [IPControllerApp] Hub listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:5900 for registration.
2016-10-10 01:14:00.677 [IPControllerApp] Hub using DB backend: 'DictDB'
2016-10-10 01:14:00.956 [IPControllerApp] hub::created hub
2016-10-10 01:14:00.957 [IPControllerApp] task::using Python leastload Task scheduler
2016-10-10 01:14:00.959 [IPControllerApp] Heartmonitor started
2016-10-10 01:14:00.967 [IPControllerApp] Creating pid file: C:\Users\Administrator\.ipython\profile_default\pid\ipcontroller.pid
2016-10-10 01:14:02.102 [IPControllerApp] client::client b'\x00\x80\x00\x00)' requested 'connection_request'
2016-10-10 01:14:02.102 [IPControllerApp] client::client [b'\x00\x80\x00\x00)'] connected
2016-10-10 01:14:47.895 [IPControllerApp] client::client b'82f5efed-52eb-46f2-8c92-e713aee8a363' requested 'registration_request'
2016-10-10 01:15:05.437 [IPControllerApp] client::client b'efe6919d-98ac-4544-a6b8-9d748f28697d' requested 'registration_request'
2016-10-10 01:15:17.899 [IPControllerApp] registration::purging stalled registration: 1`

And the ipengine log:

`2016-10-10 13:44:21.037 [IPEngineApp] Registering with controller at tcp://172.17.3.14:5900
2016-10-10 13:44:21.508 [IPEngineApp] Starting to monitor the heartbeat signal from the hub every 3010 ms.
2016-10-10 13:44:21.522 [IPEngineApp] Completed registration with id 1
2016-10-10 13:44:27.529 [IPEngineApp] WARNING | No heartbeat in the last 3010 ms (1 time(s) in a row).
2016-10-10 13:44:30.539 [IPEngineApp] WARNING | No heartbeat in the last 3010 ms (2 time(s) in a row).
...
2016-10-10 13:46:52.009 [IPEngineApp] WARNING | No heartbeat in the last 3010 ms (49 time(s) in a row).
2016-10-10 13:46:55.028 [IPEngineApp] WARNING | No heartbeat in the last 3010 ms (50 time(s) in a row).
2016-10-10 13:46:55.028 [IPEngineApp] CRITICAL | Maximum number of heartbeats misses reached (50 times 3010 ms), shutting down.`

(There is a 12.5 hour time difference between the local  machine and the remote VM)

Any idea why this may happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `--reuse`, make sure to remove the files if you change settings. It's possible that it doesn't behave well when `--reuse` is given and you change things like `--ip`, as the connection file may be overriding your command-line arguments.

When setting `--ip=0.0.0.0`, it may be useful to also set `--location=a.b.c.d` where `a.b.c.d` is an ip address of the controller that you know is accessible to the engines. Changing the

If registration works and subsequent connections don't, this may be due to a firewall only opening one port, e.g. 5900. The machine running the controller needs to have *all* the ports listed in the connection file open. You can specify these to be a port-range by manually entering port numbers in the connection files.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that the firewall had opened only the registration port. It worked after I opened all ports specified in the connection file.